# IIS site stopped SP is working, while IIS site started SP is not working

Tags: 2013, iis

I can't understand at all why thing goes wrong like that.

I have a SP2013. Evertyhing's ok. My website returns a Service Unavailable error. I stopped the IIS site, and my site is up ... and if I start the IIS site again, sp site becomes unavailable.

I don't even know what googled to solve this. Is this ever happened to someone ?

Comment: No one got this error ? Ever ? :(

Comment: have you check the iis and SP logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just fix it ! There was nothing show in logs @SalvatorDiFazio.
I comment out the `<connectionString>` in the web.config, now it works !

I still don't know why this goes wrong. It must be my bad.

EDIT : forgot to put connectionString between ` :)

Comment: Ok, now this error come back on another web application... where FBA is configured, so the `<connectionString>` is needed. And I tried to comment out the line, does not change anything. I think there is something wrong with my SharePoint server or with IIS. If someone has already encouter this type of error, let me know if you have any other solution that a fresh installation.

Answer (score 0):

So which part of the web config did you comment out? This might indicate cause or someone might spot that they got similar issue in the past, even help someone in the future :)